# What are some alternatives to interceptors in Spring 5 Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am trying to intercept my request after it enters my request controller during some of my business logic using spring webflux which is asynchronous. I know previously I could use method interceptors in spring 4 which, but what would be the alternative in spring webflux?

I was thinking about filters, but I would want to intercept the request after it has entered my controller not before.

Comment: If I get it right, you may need to create a custom Validator constraint to validate your request. If what you need is to intercept your requests to check on the header or URL path, I don't think you can escape from creating a WebFilter and intercepting your requests exchange

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.